# iPhone: chat view with buttons with different be behaviours

Tags: iphone, function, uibutton, action, selector

in my chat view user can send text message, location or an image.
Location and image are represented by a UIBUtton.
How can handle informations about the image or location to show in the selector's function?

i'm using this code to add an action on each button:

```
[locationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(seeUserLocation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(seeUserImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

How can I handle information about the image's URL or about the location to show?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it from code. You cannot pass arguments from IB.

So when a user picks a photo you should store the url in an ivar. Then when a user presses the button and calls the function seeUserImage you get the url from that ivar.